# Bad coding practice? A pre-increment in a condition with &&

Tags: c++

In my code I have

```
while (++num1begin >= 0 && isdigit(eq[num1begin]))
```

which should increment num1begin, check to see if num1begin is now greater than or equal to zero and check that other condition.

Is that bad coding practice? (And is it indeed doing what I described above?)

Comment: What would be the point of doing this? Just increment the number inside the while loop

Comment: Why write code that is difficult to understand? So much so that you post a question on this web site!

Comment: [`&&` introduces a sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) so both the `num1begin`s in the expression should be the same value when used (if this is what you mean). However I find it hard to follow. From what I can tell, the alternative requires two assignments (or an addition of separate condition statement) - to keep the increment-before behavior - but still worth the trade-off, perhaps. Write maintainable code and let the compiler deal with it :)

Comment: The code is clear and it's meaning is well defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker - If it was clear why pose the question. It is NOT clear. I just feel sorry for the sucker that has to a) review it and b) maintain it

Comment: The code would make more sense to me if it were `--`.   There must be some other loop around this one for it to make more sense.   I'm not against a `++` or a `--` in an `&&` statement.  This particular use doesn't look idiomatic, at least.  I agree with Pete, though that it is well defined.

Comment: Its weird code. It doesn't check the zero index of eq[] unless you are initializing num1begin to -1, and that would feel messy and awkward. Barring special circumstance, I would be inclined to reject it during a code review.

Answer (score 5):

Anything that has side effects in your conditions should be avoided, because it forces person reading this code to check validity few times.

In other words, it is very prone to errors and is hard to debug. If you increase your variable before or inside your `if` or `while`, it will work the same, but is much easier to understand.

Comment: I concur - Life is tricky at best so why make it harder?

Answer (score 2):

> while (++num1begin >= 0 && isdigit(eq[num1begin]))

All personal preference - there's nothing wrong with that IMHO.  I personally like the concision - and getting an extra line of context on screen - more than having `++num1begin` on the line before....

For me, I instinctively want to check the `++num1begin >= 0` logic - that takes a little mental effort but has to be done whether the increment is in the same line or on a line before.  The order of evaluation and safety with usage on the other side of the `&&` takes no thought/effort, but that will vary with the reader.  You should always think about your "audience" though... if the other programmers are professional C++  developers they should be very comfortable with this.  If they're not, and might have to stop and wonder about short-circuit evaluation and sequence points, then you might want to split it out.  Sinking to the lowest-common-denominator of code maintainer is not always best... people should learn the language... but different code bases are naturally encountered by different groups of people.

"I instinctively want to check..." - `num1begin` is used to index into `eq`, which `isdigit()` implies is a character array, so my concerns with this code include:

- whether `num1begin` is a signed type (so the first condition may ever be false),
- that `num1begin` of `-1` is not the actual sentinel value that the code's trying to avoid searching from (given sentinels of -1 and a type's most-negative value being common),
- that `num1begin >= 0` is tested on every loop iteration, but presumably only needed the first time,
- that there's no check for searching past the end of `eq`....

It may be that a correction for any of the above may warrant abandoning the current code, but if the code's functionally correct and efficient then that's fine by me.